# Prevent Asp.net MVC WebAPI from stopping (needing to press continue) when exception is caught

Tags: asp.net-web-api, exception

I have a try and catch block in a controller in my asp.net MVC webAPI project.

This is the exception that I get if I mess up the date input

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An item with the same key has already been
>   added.

i tried to add the following

```
      catch (Exception e)
        {
            output.Add("requestStatus", "fail");
            output.Add("errorSumary", "=== Exception in SOAP request ===");
            output.Add("errorSuggestion", "effectiveDate was not in the right format or the date already past");
            logger.Error("Error: ActivateController - effectiveDate was not in the right format");
        }
```

but when this exception is triggered I still have to press the continue button in visual studio to make this program keep running. **Is there any way to make it so the exception doesnt stop the running of the program? (ie so i dont have to click the green Continue button in visual studio)**

I know i should try and catch everyType of exception and handle them gracefully I just wanted a built in failsafe that allows it to keep running if one slips under the rug (and I log then using Nlog so you could see if anything is broken via something like splunk).

Comment: what is "do something"?  for what reason are you catching this specific exception vs not? "Continue" is only pressed when debugging an application, not when running one.  In a real world scenario (of the application being hosted) there is no continue button.

Comment: see the update all I am doing is catching a general exception but it stops the execution to my program. Is there any way to make it continue? 

I am making an external call to a soap API that I cannot change its code.

Comment: @Kritner I realize i had the box checked that said "break when this exception type is user-unhandled". The code was fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out in order to fix this all I had to do was change the following setting in visual studio to be checked when running in debug mode.

The setting is called

> break when this exception type is user-unhandled .

I was able to confirm this by switching the Visual Studio release configuration from "debug to Release" where the program would not only catch the exception, but the program would no longer stop its execution thus continuing to catch it time and time again without interrupting the program. I didn't realize the debug configuration by default had the "break when this exception type is user-unhandled" turned on out of the box.

You can see your exception settings in two places I have found. **Debug -> Exceptions** (and likewise set those back to the defaults if you want to re-enable this behavior).

more information about your debugging settings can be found here
**Tools->Options->Debugging**